# Spring Boot - How do I invalidate a successful authentication in AuthenticationFilter based on list of returned user authorities

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot app, I have `AuthenticationFilter` class with `attemptAuthentication` and `successfulAuthentication` methods that handle authentication:

```java
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    Authentication authentication = null;

    UserLoginRequestModel userLoginRequestModel = extractCredentials(request);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userLoginRequestModel.getUsername(), userLoginRequestModel.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());

    authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(userToken);
    
    // At this point, and once user is authenticated, I get a list of granted authorities.
    // I want to cancel the authentication (make user no longer authenticated) if the list of authorities
    // does not contain authorities I need.
    // for example, I want this user to be authenticated only if authorities contain
    // AUTHORITY-1, AUTHORITY-2, but otherwise make the authentication as NOT AUTHENTICATED.

    return authentication;
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String userId = ((UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthories = authentication.getAuthorities();

    // ... do some stuff with reponse
}
```

My authentication is working as expected and I am able to authenticate successfully.

However, being still new with Spring Security, I am trying to figure out how to invalidate a successful authentication based on below.

**Once user is authenticated in the `attemptAuthentication` method, I want to be able to cancel that authentication based on list of user authorities returned to me.**

I want to do something like in this pseudocode:

```
if (authentication.getAuthorities() does not contain AUTHORITY-1) {
  set user back to not authenticated  // HOW DO I DO THIS PART?
}
```

I have looked at some properties of `Authentication` object and I see it has `setAuthenticated(false)` but doint that changes nothing, the `successfulAuthentication` method is still invoked as when a user is successfully authenticated.

**How do I invalidate the authentication object returned in `attemptAuthentication` method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)), the implementation of the `attemptAuthentication` method should do one of the following:

> 1. Return a populated authentication token for the authenticated user,
>    indicating successful authentication
> 2. Return null, indicating that the authentication process is still in
>    progress. Before returning, the implementation should perform any
>    additional work required to complete the process.
> 3. Throw an `AuthenticationException` if the authentication process fails

To invalidate the authentication, `AuthenticationException` should be thrown. Since it's an abstract class, it cannot be thrown directly, you can create your own concrete subclass, or use one of the existing ones listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html).

Comment: Ahh, great, BadCredentialsException seam a good match or ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException.  Great, I got it, must appreciated again!  puno hvala :)